# 500 internal server error while using AJAX in a php server page

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

I am currently having problem with 500 internal server error whenever I add the ajax code to send a post request to a payment gateway but as soon as I remove the ajax code the page appears fine.

I have included `ini_set('display_errors',1);` line also but still it doesn't work. is this due to some `.htaccess` errors.

here is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
session_start();
require('./connect1.php');
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$firstname = $request->firstname;
$amount = $request->amount;
$productinfo = $request->productinfo;
$key = "LIKhkll";
$txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);
$check = "SELECT `email`,`mobile` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$firstname'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$check);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$email = $row['email'];
$phone = $row['mobile'];
}
$surl = "http://fwebsite/payment/success.php";
$furl = "http://fwebsite/payment/failure.php";
$hash = '';
$hashSequence = $key.'|'.$txnid.'|'.$amount.'|'.$productinfo.'|'.$firstname.'|'.$email;
$hash = hash("sha512", $hashSequence);

?>
```

Comment: It could be due to .htaccess errors, and if so, those errors would appear in the Apache error log (so would PHP errors, but you have already enabled display_errors at runtime). So check the Apache log first.